# Is it possible to go through an array with a pointer on a known position in C?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-address, static-memory-allocation

My question needs some explaination :

First, let's consider a 1D array of size n (dynamic or static). Let's call it tab.

We will simplify by assuming the array is stored in memory from address 0x01 to (0x01 + n - 1).

Now consider a pointer called p. And a starting index i, between 0 and n - 1.

Then we do that :

```
p = &tab[i];
```

p has know the value of the address 0x0i. (The notation isn't correct, but you get the point).

Can we read **tab[i - 1]** or **tab[i + 1]** using p like this ?

```
int iprev = *(p - 1);
int inext = *(p + 1);
```

Or simply like this ?

```
int iprev = p[-1];
int inext = p[1];
```

And eventually doing this ?

```
p--;
p++;
```

And if that is possible for 1D arrays, can it be for multi-dimensions arrays? And how to implement it in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `p + i` (for *any* `i`, positive or negative) doesn't go out of bounds in any direction (i.e., it doesn't point to before `tab[0]` or after `tab[n - 1]` in your example) then it's okay.

And remember that for *any* pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`.

---

To be more precise, it's okay to have a pointer to *anywhere*, as long as it's pointing to valid memory when you dereference the pointer.

Example:

```
int tab[N];  // Exact value of N is irrelevant
int *p = tab;  // Equal to p = &tab[0]

p--;  // After this, p will be pointing out of bounds, this is okay

// Comparing pointers is okay
if (p < tab)
{
    /* ... */
}

printf("Value of *p = %d\n", *p);  // ERROR: Here you dereference the ouf-of-bounds pointer
```

Comment: And `&p[i]` is equivalent to `p + i`.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought of. But what about a matrix. Can we use a pointer (or multiple) to achieve the same trick and how?

Comment: @MaximeBeasse What do you mean by "a matrix"? An *array of arrays*? A *jagged array/matrix*? A single "1d array" indexed as a "2d" matrix?

Comment: @MaximeBeasse Yes, although there's more than one way to implement the matrix.  You could use a geniuine two-dimensional array, or you could use a one-dimensional array containing pointers to the rows (or columns).

Comment: By matrix, I mean a 2D or 3D array. So in C, an array of array (of array).

Comment: If you have an array `int a[10][20]` then you can define `int (*p)[20]` to access it.  You can then do `p = a` and access it as `p[i][j]`.  If you do `p++` then it will move to the next row, i.e. it will skip 20 ints.

Comment: @MaximeBeasse In C an array of arrays (of arrays...) is still a *contiguous* chunk of memory. And it doesn't really matter what `&tab[i]` is pointing at, as long as you get the types correct. For `int tab[X][Y]` then `&tab[i]` is of type `int (*)[Y]`, but `tab[i]` is of type `int [Y]` which decays to `int *`. There are some very subtle semantic differences involved here, that might be hard to figure out. I recommend you draw it all out on paper and use plain plus and minus to see where a "pointer" is really pointing.

Comment: `p--;` Hmm... are you sure that it is ok? As I read "6.5.6 Additive operators" it is UB if the resulting pointer does not point into the array or points one past the last element. And J.2 Undefined behavior says: " Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an integer type produces a result that does not point into, or just beyond, the same array object (6.5.6).
"

Comment: @4386427 Reverse iteration? :)

Comment: @4386427 Regarding the J.2 quote, note that it says "... or *just beyond*, the same array object". After doing `p--` that's still *just beyond* the array.

Comment: I'm thinking... As `p` is initialized to `tab` then `p--` will be **before** `tab`. Isn't that UB

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So are you saying that "just beyond" applies to both ends of the array? So that it is both "just before" and "just after" the array?

Comment: J.2 is not normative and, in this case, uses more casual language with less context than  the rest of the standard. The normative 6.5.6 8 and 9 make it clear that pointer arithmetic is defined by the standard while the results points to an array element or to one past the last element, in the just-after direction only, not the just-before direction.

Comment: Oddly, although the comments indicate you are aware a pointer may point one beyond the last element, the text in the answer says as long as pointer arithmetic “doesn’t point to… after `tab[n-1]`”, then it is okay. But pointing to the hypothetical `tab[n]` is okay; the behavior (for pointer arithmetic, not dereferencing) is defined by the standard.

Comment: The statement “To be more precise, it's okay to have a pointer to anywhere, as long as it's pointing to valid memory when you dereference the pointer.” is not correct. It is not okay to have a pointer to `tab[-1]` or to `tab[n+1]`. If pointer arithmetic would produce a result before `tab[0]` or after `tab[n]`, the resulting behavior of the program is not defined, even if the pointer is never dereferenced.

Comment: The statement “the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`” should be clarified either by stating that `p` and `i` are not merely a pointer and an index but are in fact single identifiers or by rewriting it to “the expression `(*((p)+(i)))` is identical to `p[i]`”. (Because of the C grammar, the latter may not need any further parentheses—this is how it appears in the C standard, at 6.5.2.1 2.)